# IPhone sdk Login Control Segue issue

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Hi I am new to Iphone Development and using iphone sdk5.

I am trying to implement an application through which I can login and show my application if login is successful, otherwise show the error alert.

problem which I am facing right now is that I have first view as View controller and I want to send the login details through clicking the login button and I want to perform the Segue through the same button if the Login is success full and show my TabBar Application. I have tried to implement basic push Segue as well as Custom segue... someway I was able to do through custom segue by checking the if(Flag)..then perform the segue... but the point is that I set the flag when i see the login is correct otherwise it should not set the Flag... now when I run the application I have to click the button twice and then the segue is performed and I get to my application TabBarController..

Please share some alternate ways also if you have better suggestions for me...

Any Ideas... please answer as soon as possible..
Thanks for time

Answer (score 1):

The best method I can think of is:

1. You can **ctrl-drag from the First view controller to the Second view** (tab view controller). [You can use the view controller object at the bottom of the scene to do this.]
2. **Create a identifier** for the segue which was created, on the right hand side.
3. Define a IBAction for your **Login** button
4. Inside the IBAction do your FLAG checks
5. **If the condition is TRUE** then you call the

   ```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"identifier_name_you_gave" sender:self];
   ```